# How do I cancel software updates that are downloading on Mountain Lion

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, software-update

I have installed Mountain Lion. Software Update has now been integrated in to the App Store application. I clicked the Update button to start downloading software updates for the OS, but now I see that there are almost 7GB of updates and I want to cancel the download. Is there any way to cancel software updates for the OS that are currently downloading on Mountain Lion?

Comment: Disconnect the Internet.

Answer (score 5):

I encountered  the same issue. I couldn't stop, pause or quit from a system software update.

The solution is to disconnect from your network then quit App Store. That's it.

Comment: This almost worked.  However, I had to leave App Store running and wait (after unplugging the network cable) for the download progress to disappear (in App Store) and the `Cancel` button to change back to an `Update` button.  Without waiting, the download would resume (even if App Store was **not** running) as soon as I plugged the network cable back in.

Answer (score 0):

This may have already been solved, but the only options I have are either force-quitting the App Store or rebooting the computer.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple just open the app store and navigate to updates and then press "option" key then that pause button will change to cancel button click on and done your update is canceled.

Answer (score 0):

open Activity monitor, kill(force quit) either Appstore or systemupdated process.